# Verify that all nodes at given level have different values in binary tree

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, binary-tree

My question is, can this problem be solved **without** using any data structures (stack, list, etc) or it requires one? (I would also like to see the solution in both cases, if possible).

---

The problem:

Having a BinaryTree class that represents binary trees that contains integer values. Assume that there are already implemented methods:

```
public BinaryTree right();  // returns right children
public BinaryTree left();   // returns left children
public int val();   // returns value of root node.
```

Implement the following **recursive** method :

```
public static boolean allDifferentAtLevel(BinaryTree a, int lev){...}
```

that receives a Binary Tree of integers and returns **true** only if all the values of the nodes of *a* at level *lev* all have different values.

---

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I can easily solve this using extra data structure. Like I can take a global DS for this problem. Do u want a solution with extra DS ?

Comment: Also can u paste the class structure of Node and BinaryTree class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `HashSet<Integer>` to keep track of the data present at `lev`th level.

```
public static boolean allDifferentAtLevel(BinaryTree a, int lev){
    return checker(new HashSet<Integer>(),a,0,lev); //EmptySet, Root, CurrentLevel, Level
}

public static boolean checker(HashSet<Integer> set,BinaryTree a, int currentLevel, int lev) {
    if(a==null) //If current node of tree is null, return true.
        return true;

    if(currentLevel==lev) //If currentLevel is the required level, We don't need to move further.
                          //We can just validate the data at currentLevel and return the appropriate value.
    {
        int value=a.val();
        if(set.contains(value)) //If set contains the value, Duplication found.
            return false;

        set.add(value);
        return true;
    }

    //Check for both of the children.
    return checker(set,a.left(),currentLevel+1,lev) && checker(set,a.right(),currentLevel+1,lev);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible however it would be inefficient - you can implement two recursive functions:

1. Doing DFS reach all the nodes at required level
2. From the first function (for each node at required level) call another function that'll count (also using DFS) all the nodes with values equal to the value of the node considered by the first function and check that this count is equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is solveable with recursion without additional data structures.

Let's try to define what the `allDifferentAtLevel(BinaryTree tree, int lev)` method should look like for different `lev`s:

For `lev=0` the result is simply `false` since all nodes on the level `0` have the same values. There's just one node on level `0` so *all* nodes have the same value.

For `lev=1` it is quite trivial to check `tree.right().val() == tree.left().val()` (add `null` checks).

For higher levels (`lev>1`) you should call the method recursively. Basically, `allDifferentAtLevel(tree.left(), lev - 1)` and `allDifferentAtLevel(tree.right(), lev - 1)` would make sure that left subtree and right subtree satisfy the condition. Unfortunately this is insufficient since left and right subtrees may have some common value between them.

But it is possible to work around this checking not just left and right but all combinations of subtrees two levels deeper. Something like:

```
BinaryTree ll = tree.left() == null ? null : tree.left().left();
BinaryTree lr = tree.left() == null ? null : tree.left().right();
BinaryTree rl = tree.right() == null ? null : tree.right().left();
BinaryTree rr = tree.right() == null ? null : tree.right().right();

BinaryTree ll_lr = tree.left();
BinaryTree ll_rl = new BinaryTree(0, ll, rl);
BinaryTree ll_rr = new BinaryTree(0, ll, rr);
BinaryTree lr_rl = new BinaryTree(0, lr, rl);
BinaryTree lr_rr = new BinaryTree(0, lr, rr);
BinaryTree rl_rr = tree.right();

return allDifferentAtLevel(ll_lr, lev - 1) &&
       allDifferentAtLevel(ll_rl, lev - 1) &&
       allDifferentAtLevel(ll_rr, lev - 1) &&
       allDifferentAtLevel(lr_rl, lev - 1) &&
       allDifferentAtLevel(lr_rr, lev - 1) &&
       allDifferentAtLevel(rl_rr, lev - 1);
```

There are four subtrees two levels deeper (`ll`, `lr`, `rl`, `rr`). But we can't just check these subtrees, we have to check them against each other. There are six possible distinct pairs of these subtrees. In order to check these subtrees against each other, we can create one binary tree for each of the distinct pairs (`ll_lr`, `ll_rl`, `ll_rr`, `lr_rl`, `lr_rr`, `rl_rr`) and then check each of these binary trees recursively. If any of the subtrees `ll`, `lr`, `rl`, `rr` have equal elements on the `lev-2`, there will be a pair of them having equal element on the `lev-1`.

So yes, the problem is solveable with recursion without additional data structures. I don't consider `BinaryTree` an additional data structure here.

Having said this, using an additional data structure like a set would make the task easier.